# How to find and change DataViewListCtrl BackgroundColour of Selected text in WxPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, background, wxpython, wxwidgets

My problem is I can't find the command to change the background color of `DataViewListCtrl` for `selected` text/row/item in `DataViewListCtrl` object.
I looked into the documentation but there's no apparent reference.

https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.dataview.DataViewCtrl.html#wx-dataview-dataviewctrl

I'm using the `sample_one.py` script from this reference:

https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20add%20a%20menu%20bar%20in%20the%20title%20bar%20%28Phoenix%29

The `DataViewListCtrl` has this example code:

```
        self.dvlc = dv.DataViewListCtrl(
            self,
            style=dv.DV_MULTIPLE
            | dv.DV_ROW_LINES
            | dv.DV_HORIZ_RULES
            | dv.DV_VERT_RULES,
        )

        self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#ffffff")
        self.dvlc.SetForegroundColour("black")
```

What I'm looking to do is similar to Tkinter example below (change the selected text background color to blue):

```
style.configure(
    "Treeview", background="#FFFFDD", foreground="black", fieldbackground="#FFFFDD"
)
style.map("Treeview", background=[("selected", "#F0FFFF")])
```

I haven't been able to try a workaround yet as I'm not sure how to get the needed command/value, but on my end the selected `DataViewListCtrl` items have a `#242424` color (I checked with an eyedropper from a screenshot).

I found the  2 parameters `IsSelected` and `IsRowSelected` in the doc:

https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl.html#wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl.IsRowSelected

https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.dataview.DataViewCtrl.html#wx.dataview.DataViewCtrl.IsSelected

and tested as

```
        self.dvlc = dv.DataViewListCtrl(
            self,
            style=dv.DV_MULTIPLE
            | dv.DV_ROW_LINES
            | dv.DV_HORIZ_RULES
            | dv.DV_VERT_RULES,
        )

        # Give it some columns.
        self.dvlc.AppendTextColumn("Id", width=40)
        self.dvlc.AppendTextColumn("Artist", width=170)
        self.dvlc.AppendTextColumn("Title", width=260)
        self.dvlc.AppendTextColumn("Genre", width=80)

        # Load the data. Each item (row) is added as a sequence
        # of values whose order matches the columns.
        for itemvalues in musicdata:
            self.dvlc.AppendItem(itemvalues)

        # — 1st test with same result as 2nd below
        # if self.dvlc.IsSelected == True:
        #    self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#0066ff")
        # else:
        #    self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#F0FFFF")


        if self.dvlc.IsRowSelected == True:
            self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#0066ff")
        else:
            self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#F0FFFF")

        self.dvlc.SetForegroundColour("black")
```

I tried also without the `== True` explicit as

```
        # — 1st test with same result as 2nd below
        # if self.dvlc.IsSelected:
        #    self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#0066ff")
        # else:
        #    self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#F0FFFF")


        if self.dvlc.IsRowSelected:
            self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#0066ff")
        else:
            self.dvlc.SetBackgroundColour("#F0FFFF")
```

and the unexpected blue background displays by default (when not selected).

Is there some documented "selected" parameter or otherwise known working method to be able to capture the selected background color and change it in WxPython?

Comment: For later ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5875791

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a custom renderer if you want to change the way the selected items background is rendered -- and you will have to overwrite the entire background entirely, as the default one will still be drawn, you will just be able to paint over it.

Alternatively, you can define a custom `wxRendererNative`-derived object and override its `DrawItemSelectionRect()` method and then set it as the renderer to use globally. This should be simpler, but it will change selection drawing in all controls using this function.

Comment: Thanks @VZ. I found the `customRendered.py` script from the demo https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/samples/dataview/CustomRenderer.py
I could reproduce the output in the `sample_one.py` from the 
*How to add a menu bar in the title bar (Phoenix)* script https://web.archive.org/web/20221205171553/https://pastebin.com/91cGswJE

Here's the code: https://pastecode.io/s/zor7nbw4
(new comment for lenght below)

Comment: I'm facing the 4 issues displayed in the screenshot: 
https://i.imgur.com/PVg6IjU.png
Why the Id column does not render the blue background?
How to override the full cell with the rendrerer, not just the text length?
Why the elipses show up (also in the demo)?
How to change the text foreground color when selected as well?